# revoke and delete file after specific time asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I had implemented file uploading on my website and I make a download link for the user in this way: [(Random GUID).(File Extensions)]

I want to **revoke** the generated download link and delete the uploaded file after 10 minutes, or revoke the download link after the first download request.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add some details how u're trying to implement this? Like: Do you want to use a background worker thread to delete the files? How do you want to persist the information which files are invalid at which time? Are u using a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the file you either need to write a Windows Service to poll the  files, or if you want to keep it really basic you can check for old files every time the page loads.

Here's the basic version:

When a user requests a download, check the creation date of all files in the target directory.  If a file is over 10 minutes old - delete it.  After clearing up the files it's then a simple check to see if the target file the user has requested still exists or not

You can check the creation date and delete files using the following:

```
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\_Temp", "*.txt");
        foreach (string file in files) {
            DateTime creation = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
            if (((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - creation)).TotalMinutes > 10) {
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
```

NOTE: Make sure you don't have any important files in the target directory.  Change "*.txt" to match the file format of your uploaded files.

Next, check if the requested file still exists using:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\test.txt")) { 
    // process file here
}
```

Hope that helps :)